# Как подобрать регулярное выражение вида "не должен содержать" слово

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, пожалуйста, регулярное выражение для составления правила:

Строка НЕ содержит `СТРОКА1`.

Контекст: вытащить из mongo документы, в одном поле должно быть это `СТРОКА1`, а в другом этой `СТРОКА1` не должно быть.

Делаю как-то так:

```
$q = 'СТРОКА1';

$regex = new \MongoRegex("/.*{$q}|ALL.*/i");

$regex_deny = new \MongoRegex("/[^({$q})]/i");

$documents = $document_manager->getRepository('MyDocument')->findBy(array(

            'field1' => $regex,

            'field2' => $regex_deny,

        ));
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^(?!(.*СТРОКА1))/
```

т.е. в вашем случае, как я понимаю:

```
/^(?!(.*{$q}))/
```

[Демо](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/iG8)

Comment: Спасибо, то, что нужно!

Comment: Наш сайт отличается от социальных сетей. Он помогает решать прикладные задачи. Поэтому мы используем комментарии только по делу — уточнить проблему, дать конструктивную критику или добавить полезную информацию.

Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers